# Не могу отобразить первое отрицательное число в массиве

Tags: c, массивы

задание таково :

> Ввести массив (rand()) вывести первый положительный и последний отрицательный элементы и их позиции.

Мой код:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void main() {
  setlocale(0, "");
  srand(time(NULL));
  int n, i, plus = 0, minus = 0, minus1 = 0, plus1 = 0, minus2 = 0, plus2 = 0;
  printf("Введите количество чисел в массиве \n");
  scanf("%d", & n);
  int a[n];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a[i] = rand() % 100 - 50;
    printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    if (a[i] > 0 && minus2 == 0) {
      minus = a[i];
      minus1 = i;
      minus2++;
    }
    if (a[i] < 0 && plus2 == 0) {
      plus = a[i];
      plus = i;
      plus2++;
    }
  }
  printf("\nПервое положительное число = %d, порядка %d. \n Первое отрицательное число = %d, порядка %d.", minus, minus1, plus, plus1);
}
```

C положительным числом проблем не возникло , а вот отрицательно выводит неправильно .

Comment: `plus=a[i];plus=i;` тут затираете

Comment: Я отформатировал ваш код, думаю, что теперь вам не составит труда и самому найти ошибку. Как вы поняли, адекватно отформотированный код гораздо легче читать и отлаживать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

надо

```
if (a[i]<0&&plus2==0) {plus=a[i];plus1=i;/*вот тут ошибка*/ plus2++;}
```

а вообще у вас алгоритм содержит одну принципиальную ошибку (правда возникающую с вероятностью 0.5^n)

если так получилось, что у вас вообще не содержится отрицательных или положительных чисел, то ваш алгоритм все равно выдает значение `позиция:0, значение:0`

вообще лучше, если число не определено использовать отрицательную позицию, тогда вам не потребуется вводить лишних переменных:

```
  int plus_value = 0, 
      minus_value = 0, 
      plus_pos = -1, 
      minus_pos = -1;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      a[i] = rand() % 100 - 50;
      printf("%d\t", a[i]);

      // рассматриваем все отрицательные значения и записываем позицию последнего
      if (a[i] < 0) {
          minus_value = a[i]; 
          minus_pos = i;
      }

      // рассматриваем положительные значения только тогда, когда не было найдено ни одного положительного значения ранее (позиция остается неопределённой - -1)
      if (a[i] > 0 && plus_pos == -1) {
          plus_value = a[i]; 
          plus_pos = i;
      }
  }
```

Кроме того вам требуется выявить первый положительный элемент, а значит как только вы нашли элемент проверку выполнять дальше не следует, поэтому

1. для отрицательного числа (которое надо найти последнее) проверяется каждый элемент

   ```
   if (a[i] < 0) {
   ```
2. для положительного числа (которое надо найти первое) проверяется элемент до тех пор пока не будет найден первый положительный элемент

   ```
   if (a[i] > 0 && plus_pos == -1) {
   ```

P.S.

Ну и соответственно когда вы выводите результаты - проверяйте `minus_pos` и `plus_pos` на `-1` и выводите соответствующий текст - типа `положительных чисел найдено не было`

Запомните - чем меньше n, тем выше шанс, что это случится, а при n = 1 шанс равен 100%, что или отрицательных или положительных или и тех и других найдено не будет (например в массиве только 0 будет)

а за что автора вопроса минусуют?

Comment: После первого `if` можно поставить `else`. Нет смысла проверять на положительность если элемент уже отрицательный

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, конечно, но это `экономия на спичках`, т.е. компиляторы сейчас очень умные (зачастую умнее программистов) и они такие вещи могут соптимизировать сами гораздо лучше, чем нам кажется, если посмотреть в дизассемблере может там и будет else (ну вернее ассемблерный код, аналогичный данной логике) стоять